# How to pass a variable through a URL (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

How can I pass some argument(s) through a URL using a clean url:

From this:

```
http://example.com/something/index.html?Use_Id=abc
```

To this:

```
http://example.com/something/abc
```

Comment: you want to parse `abc` from the url? you have rewrited urls?

Comment: Are you using nodejs? If not, do you use mod_rewrite? So to make this clear: You want that http://example.com/something/abc routes to http://example.com/something/index.html?Use_Id=abc without changing the addressbar?

Comment: I want to use http://example.com/something/abc (to send trough an e-mail message or sms) and get the same results as if I were using http://example.com/something/index.html?Use_Id=abc Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but to solve that, we need to know what kind of webserver are you running? Nodejs? Apache? lighttp? nginx?

Comment: Insufficient information to answer the question. You should be more specific, providing as many details as you can, or people trying to help you will just waste their time.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "pass a variable through a URL". Perhaps you could rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com/something/abc?use_id="+your_value_variable
```

and if you need more than one, just add it to the string.

Comment: that's not what OP asked